# Does Windows 7 E include Anytime Upgrade?

Tags: windows, windows-7

As many of us are aware Windows 7 (Home and Pro) E are available for pre-order.

Given everyone in the EU is only given the option of buying the 'E' version, will this version still have the 'Anytime Upgrade' option once installed (i.e would I be able to upgrade to Ultimate at a later date - would this be known as Ultimate 'E'?). My only worry is that the Anytime Upgrade might only work with non- 'E' versions.

If my theory is correct then if I wanted to buy now then upgrade later I may be better ordering from an American website.

Also - I realize the initial install has to be clean with the 'E' versions.

Anyone have anything concrete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning for not offering Upgrades with the E versions is due to the fact that removing IE when upgradng (to comply with the European Court), can cause problems with existing software, hence no upgrade.

You would assume that if you are upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 7, this would not be an issue as you would not need to remove IE, its either not there, or you have installed it yourself, in which case it can be left.

I have no definite information to say whether or not it will, but to me it makes sense to make it available on the E version as well.

Comment: Thanks Sam. - Yes I would hope they add in the Anytime Upgrade for the E versions. It just makes me skeptical as this is one of those add versions just to keep the EU commission happy.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that both the E version and the standard version would be offered in the EU, thus satisfying the EU court by making the offer, similar to how Windows Media Player was handled. Both a non Media Player and a regular Media Player player version was available and it was up to the customer to order the version they wanted.

Comment: You may well be right, I cant see a non 'E' version for example on Amazon.co.uk for pre-order but that might be because MS want EU customers to go for the 'E' edition. I will keep checking. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The 'E' edition will be the only version available in Europe - http://microsoftontheissues.com/cs/blogs/mscorp/archive/2009/06/11/working-to-fulfill-our-legal-obligations-in-europe-for-windows-7.aspx

Comment: Nice link Sam. I stand corrected :-) The initial news reports had different scenarios, but obviously it was just speculation.